# How to write a VMS daemon using python?

Tags: python, daemon, openvms

There are plenty entries on the internet on how to create a daemon using python in unix but I couldn't find anything mentioning how to do this in OpenVMS. Does anybody know how to create daemons (or VMS equivalent) in OpenVMS using python?

Comment: Why is there a vote to close? This isnt a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to run it like that:

```
$ run /detach /process=daemon_name python_program
```

[More information here](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/9996/9996pro_168.html)